# Deb fails to install if space is in file name

Tags: ios, debian, jailbreak, dpkg

So in my app I have a table view. If a file is a deb, it asks to install, press install and it takes me to a view controller which shows the install, similar to iFile and Cydia (not as glamorous with the output lol).

All is fine in that aspect. It installs. However. If a file has a space in the name, i.e. `random File.deb`, it fails. I noticed that iFile has it figured out, tried contacting them to see if they could enlighten me on the situation, but no response yet.

How would I escape the space? or make it seem like dpkg doesn't care it's there?

This is how I call and execute the install.

```
MyDownloadsViewController * vc = [[MyDownloadsViewController alloc] init];
vc.fileName = debName;

// Get documents folder
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
path = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
path = [[@"~/Documents/myFolder" stringByExpandingTildeInPath] retain];

NSString *debPath = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:vc.fileName];

//NSTask    
NSTask *task = [[NSTask alloc] init];
NSPipe *pipe = [NSPipe pipe];
[task setLaunchPath: myLaunchPath];
[task setArguments: [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"/usr/bin/dpkg", @"-i", debPath, @"2>/tmp/dpkg.log" ,nil]];
[task setStandardOutput: pipe];
[task launch];
```

I've tried using:

```
[filename stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""]
```

in both the downloads to send the file and in the output view controller to receive it. It either fails or the app crashes.

I've also tried:

```
if ( [fileName rangeOfString:@" "].location != NSNotFound ) {
    appendedFile = [path stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];        
}
```

To determine is the file has a space, if not proceed like normal. That had some unwanted results in the same fashion, plus it would install whatever the last deb in the table view was.

Would it be better to use 2 NSTasks. 1 to unpack and the 2nd to configure? Ive tried that but it wouldn't go onto the second task, or it would still see the first one running and lock dpkg.

Any insight or knowledge would be appreciated.

Comment: you cannot use `2>/tmp/dpkg.log` as an argument to NSTask, because that argument should be interpreted by a shell, and not by `dpkg`. NSTask does not automatically interpret shell-like syntax like `|` or `>`!

Comment: dpkg.log is a log file created when my table view is opened. Once a deb is tapped to install, it reads the output printed to that log file. It may not be a "proper" way, but it works for what I am doing.

Answer (score 1):

You're executing a command line app, so you **HAVE** to execute as if you were typing that at the shell prompt yourself.

This installs a package named from a file named `foo`, and passes some extra weird/unknown argument `bar.deb` to `dpkg`

```
/usr/bin/dpkg -i foo bar.deb
```

This installs a package from a file named 'foo bar.deb'

```
/usr/bin/dpkg -i "foo bar.deb"
```

Note the quotes... You could also use `\` to escape the space, but then you have to realize that you have to DOUBLE escape: once for  your obj-C, and ones for the shell.

Comment: How would I escape the space if the space could be at a random spot in the file name?